# NextJS - ky-universal error - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use [ky-universal](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky-universal) in a NextJS project however just using the library gives this error:

```
import fetch, {Headers, Request, Response} from 'node-fetch';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am just making a test request in a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const response = ky.get('https://test.com');
  console.log(response);
});
```

I'm going around in circle and can't get this to work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: There is an active discussion going on here about the issue which may eventually result in a solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/21252